# how to pass thymeleaf object to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring-boot, thymeleaf and Angularjs. In my my  view.html I need to recover the list "lstUsers" from my class "controller.java" using Angular.

For informations: "view.html" and "controller.java" works good. The problem  is how I can fill my variable "$scope.users" with "lstUsers"

this is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.users = []; 

    $scope.users = $lstUsers;   // (lstUsers) is an object from controller.java:  this not work !!!!!!! 

    $scope.sort = function(keyname){
        $scope.sortKey = keyname;   //set the sortKey to the param passed
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; //if true make it false and vice versa
    }
});
```

this is my view.html

```
<body>
    <div role="main" class="container theme-showcase">
      <div class="" style="margin-top:90px;">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="bs-component" ng-controller="listdata">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control input-style search-input" placeholder="Search" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <table class="table table-responsive table-hover table-striped table-bordered tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-click="sort('id')">Id
                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='id'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('first_name')">First Name
                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='first_name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('last_name')">Last Name
                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='last_name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th ng-click="sort('hobby')">Hobby
                                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='hobby'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr dir-paginate="user in users|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5">
                            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{user.hobby}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
                <dir-pagination-controls
                    max-size="5"
                    direction-links="true"
                    boundary-links="true" >
                </dir-pagination-controls>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <script th:src="@{/js/angular/angular.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/dirPagination.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/app.js}"></script>
  </body>
```

this is a snippet of my controller.java

```
...
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getSubTasks")
    public ModelAndView getSubTasks(@RequestParam String issueKey) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

            .....

            model.setViewName("view");
            model.addObject("lstUsers", getUsers());

        }

        return model;
    }
...
```

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of data is retrieved from the server via ajax. For example you can provide a Spring MVC Controller that returns your sub tasks as a JSON array and your angular app would need to retrieve that data from your Spring MVC Controller via ajax.

Have a look at this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks xSNRG, the software architecte of the application impose to do something like that. This is why I need to retrieve data like that

Comment: In this case, the data will only be loaded once, when the whole page is loaded and will never change. If you need this, however, you need to serialize your Java Sub-Tasks list into a JSON String to be able to initially assign it to $scope.users in your Angular controller. Here is an example how to serialize java objects to JSON: mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json. You can then create the JSON string in your Spring MVC Controller and read it in your thymeleaf template, where you can assign it to the Angular controller vadiable.

Comment: How I can retrieve the serialize Object in app.js ?

Comment: I did like that $scope.subtasks = $lstOtherSubTasks;  but it's not working